# Having difficulty with outputting file

Tags: java

So we've started learning some file handling and Im currently writing some code to output and file to text, when that file has been written I need to open it again and extract information and then output that information to another file, the problem Im having is when I go to extract that information it seems to overwrite both files and they both end up blank. The first part of the code in my switch statement works, but I can't seem to figure out where my error is, any help would be greatly appreciated! =]

So here is my handler for the lines

```
public class AssignementHandler {   
private String studentNo;
private String studentName;
private int result1;

public String getstudentNo() {
  return studentNo;
}

public String getstudentName() {
  return studentName;
}
public int getResult1() {
  return result1;
}

public static boolean checkStringForDigits(String s){
      for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++){
         if(!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
             return false;
      }return true;
}

public void lineSeperate(String line){
      //read each char until I find a digit
    int i = 0; 
    while(!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)))//while it is not a space
        i++; //keep going

      //stops when I find a space - so this is the start of the name
    studentNo = line.substring(0, i).trim();

    int nameStart = i; 
    while(!Character.isDigit(line.charAt(i)))//while it is not a space
        i++; //keep going

    studentName = line.substring(nameStart, i).trim();


    result1 =  Integer.parseInt(line.substring(i).trim());
}
```

and then my tester is as follows

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

public class studentTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, RuntimeException {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;

    do{
        System.out.println("\nStudent Application\n*******************");
        System.out.println("1. Enter Student Details");
        System.out.println("2. Write test marks to results.txt and highest.txt");
        System.out.println("3. Display contents of any file on screen");
        System.out.println("0. Quit\n*******************");
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter option: ");
        option = keyIn.nextInt();

        String studentNo;
        String studentName;
        int result1;

        PrintWriter studentOUT = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("student.txt"));
        AssignementHandler handlelines = new AssignementHandler();

        switch (option) { //start switch
        case 1: //add Student Details - Menu Option 1
            char userResponse = 'y';
            System.out.print("\nOption Selected - Enter Student Details" + "\n------------------\n");
            keyIn.nextLine(); //clear buffer of option 1


            System.out.print("Please enter student number in the format L0000000: ");
            studentNo = keyIn.nextLine();

            if(studentNo.length() !=9){
                System.out.println("Incorrect Length: Must have 1 Letter and 8 Numbers!");
                continue;
            }
            else if(!(Character.isLetter(studentNo.charAt(0)))){
                System.out.println("Student Number must begin with a Letter!");
                continue;
            }
            else if(!AssignementHandler.checkStringForDigits(studentNo)){
                //if it returns false
                System.out.println("Incorrect Format, Student Number Must Have 8 numbers!" );
                continue;
            }



            System.out.print("Please Enter Student Name: ");
            studentName = keyIn.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Please Enter Result - (1): ");
            result1 = keyIn.nextInt();
            studentOUT.println(studentNo + " " + studentName + " " + result1);

            do{
                System.out.print("Do you want to add another student?: \n" +
                        "(Y) or (N)");
                userResponse = keyIn.next().charAt(0);
                keyIn.nextLine(); //clear buffer


            }while (userResponse != 'n');


            studentOUT.close();
            System.out.println("Student Records have been written successfully to - student.txt - !");

            break;


            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        case 2: //write test marks to results.txt and highest.txt - Menu Option 2

            System.out.print("\nOption Selected - Write Files" + "\n------------------\n");
            System.out.println("Files have been written successfully!");
            keyIn.nextLine(); //clear buffer of option 2

            Scanner studentsIN = new Scanner(new File("student.txt"));
            try{

                PrintWriter resultsOut = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("results.txt", true)); 


              try{

                     while(studentsIN.hasNextLine()){

                         String line = studentsIN.nextLine(); //read the next line
                         //System.out.println(line);  //for testing
                         //process the line
                         handlelines.lineSeperate(line);
                         String studentNumber = handlelines.getstudentNo(); 
                         //String studName = handlelines.getstudentName();
                         int resultIN = handlelines.getResult1();

                         //write to the file
                         resultsOut.printf(studentNumber+""+resultIN+"");


                     }//end while
                  }//inner try - files are open and being processed 
              finally{

                  studentsIN.close(); 
                  resultsOut.close();

              } 
            }//end outer try
            catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                System.out.println(ex); 
            }
            catch(RuntimeException ex){
                System.out.println(ex); 
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex); 
            }

        break;




            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        case 0:
            System.out.println("Results Application shutting down...\n******** Goodbye ********"); //quit program
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option entered ");

        }//end switch
    }while (option != 0); //end user interface
}//end main method

}//end class studentTester
```

it just seems to write two blank files without extracting the the information I need, not sure what I am doing wrong here as Im following some previous examples we did in class.

Comment: Hi there! Could you please encapsulate your program logic from your problem using methods. Like e.g. creating a method for the stuff that happens for every case in main. This would make the code much more readable and debugable. ^^-d

Comment: BTW you never touch highest.txt other than in printed output or commentary ;)

Comment: aye I figured it out thanks =]  only issue Im having now is with parseInt lol, I can get the first result to the file, but after that I get a numberformat exception error, dont know how to deal with it, I belive my linehandler is incorrect on how to sort it =/